# sql select in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using plsql developer with oracle db

and i'm trying to select from some selection.

```
select *
  from (select max(mrs.no), mrs.material_id
      from material_route_step mrs, documents d
     where d.document_id(+) = mrs.document_id
       and mrs.prod_order_id = 121673
       and d.document_type_id = 1
       and mrs.unit_id = 2606
     group by mrs.material_id) as sa,
   material_route_step mrs1,
   documents d1
where mrs1.material_id = sa.material_id
  and mrs1.no = sa.no
  and d.name like '%N%'
```

But i think my syntax isn't right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't know your db, table and query. Can you please explain what ur query do? why you think ur syntax is not right? what you want as output?

Comment: And what is the problem you have? Is there any error? Also, [Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3178).

Comment: remove `as` in `as sa`. And it should be `d1.name like '%N%'`. Finally `select * from ..`, wont you want to fetch only the columns you want? Not an error, but might be confusing!

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar was right. An error was caused because of 'as' that's all. thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your "d.name" reference might be incorrect as the "d" alias is on your Inner query vs d1 in your OUTER query... Maybe that should be a "d1.name", but you should also include your left-outer join (+) reference by the document ID too otherwise you will have a Cartesian result.

```
where
    mrs1.material_id = sa.material_id
    and mrs1.no = sa.no
    and d1.document_id(+) = mrs1.document_id
    and d1.name like '%N%'
```

But, to better offer an answer, I will try to answer by writing what I THINK you are looking for, then a query to get that.  Since you are looking for the maximum "mrs.no", this would imply you want a JOIN and not a left-join via Oracle's syntax of (+)=, but for a specific product, document type and unit.  Once that has been found, get every document name associated with the materials route.

```
select
      *
   from
      ( select
              mrs.material_id,
              max( mrs.no ) as maxno
           from
              material_route_step mrs
                 JOIN documents d
                    on mrs.document_id = d.document_id
                   AND d.document_type_id = 1
           where
                  mrs.prod_order_id = 121673
              and mrs.unit_id = 2606
           group by
              mrs.material_id ) PreQuery
         JOIN material_route_step mrs2
            on PreQuery.material_id = mrs2.material_id
           AND PreQuery.maxno = mrs2.no
           JOIN documents d2
              on mrs2.document_id = d2.document_id
```

Without applying a join condition on your outer documents "d1" alias, you WILL get a Cartesian result set.